# Flutter why firstChild has no size after calling addInitialChild()

Tags: flutter, layout, render

I’d like to override performLayout in RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor ,when I called addInitialChild,I got a firstChild without size. But,
When I called insertAndLayout() and collectGarbage(1,0),then use insertAndLayoutLeadingChild , I got the same firstChild and contained size I want.

Comment: When doing a Stackoverflow post it is important to provide any information that helps to debug your code. In particular, instead of describing with words your code, it is recommended to provide the code fragment that gives you the problem and add comments to it explaining what you are trying to do. Furthermore, when you get an error, it is recommended to add also the stack trace, since most of the time it is self-explanatory and allows other developers to understand what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use firstChild!.layout(constraints,parentsUseSize:true) can slove that problem, it will apply size to firstChild….